# ARC dealloc called on thread other than mainthread

Tags: ios, uiwebview, automatic-ref-counting, dealloc

I've got an issue using ARC.

Every time my dealloc methode is called on a thread other than the main thread, I've got a bad access. with the message : 
*Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...*

Which doesn't suprise me cause I've a webview beeing working in my controller.
most of the time, when I use my app normaly, dealloc is called on the mainThread, but if I do monkey, and push, and pop my controller very fast, the dealloc might be called on another thread.

I tried to look for a way to avoid the dealloc if not on mainthread, but I could'nt find a way with ARC compilation.

SO I'm kind of stuck with my webview in my controller !

thanks for your help

edit : here is my BT
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set your UIWebView delegate to nil before you dealloc it.

Comment: No. delegates are weak references. Weak refs don't have any effect on referencing-count. When objects that weak variables referenced are dealloced it'll be set nil automatically.